# A* pathfinding - Logical error?

Tags: lua, logic, path-finding

***All the code is in Lua / Pseudo Code***

I'm attempting to write an A* pathfinder. However, I seem to be getting some errors.  I'm not sure if my procedure is right...

```
local function AStar(Start, Goal)
    Start["GScore"] = 0 -- Distance from start.  
    Start["HScore"] = Heuristic(Start,Goal) -- Estimated Distance from Goal
    Start["FScore"] = Start.GScore + Start.HScore -- The Final Score
```

I think the above code is right...

Now....  The data structure I'm using is an array of 'Nodes', which contain a table with:

- X
- Y
- Source (Pointer to another node)
- GScore
- HScore
- FScore

And I have a preassembled map which has...

- X
- Y
- table of neighbors (In X/Y format, but no Source, GScore, etc).

To try to cutdown on calculations.

### Heuristics

The heusticis I'm using is...

```
function Heuristic(Start, Goal)
    return math.sqrt(((Start.X-Goal.X)^2) + ((Start.Y-Goal.Y)^2))
end
```

Euclidean Distance, although I was trying to use Chebyshev distance.  I think that worked, but I can't be sure, so I switch to what I considered a 'Fail safe' Heuristic until I thought it would work... But then you get...

```
S = Start
E = End

       S
      ***
     *****
      ***
       E
```

When pathfinding, where...

```
       S
      **O
     ****O
      **O
       E
```

Could *Technically* be the correct path. I'm not sure if you have any workarounds for that either.  I was doing....

```
function HeuristicDiagonal(Start, Goal)
    return min(abs(Start.X-Goal.X), abs(Start.Y-Goal.Y))
end

function HeuristicStraight(Start, Goal)
    return abs(Start.X-Goal.X) + abs(Start.Y - Goal.Y)
end

function Heuristic(Start, Goal)
    local HD = HeuristicDiagonal(Start, Goal)
    return ((HD*1.414) + ((HeuristicStraight(Start, Goal) - (2*HD))))*1.01
end
```

But it seemed to degrade into bestsearch thingy.

### Basis Of Code / Algorithm

I'm trying to follow this instruction:

```
OPEN = priority queue containing START
CLOSED = empty set
while lowest rank in OPEN is not the GOAL:
  current = remove lowest rank item from OPEN
  add current to CLOSED
  for neighbors of current:
    cost = g(current) + movementcost(current, neighbor)
    if neighbor in OPEN and cost less than g(neighbor):
      remove neighbor from OPEN, because new path is better
    if neighbor in CLOSED and cost less than g(neighbor): **
      remove neighbor from CLOSED
    if neighbor not in OPEN and neighbor not in CLOSED:
      set g(neighbor) to cost
      add neighbor to OPEN
      set priority queue rank to g(neighbor) + h(neighbor)
      set neighbor's parent to current

reconstruct reverse path from goal to start
by following parent pointers

(**) This should never happen if you have an monotone admissible heuristic. However in games we often have inadmissible heuristics.
```

From this source [ http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/ImplementationNotes.html#sketch ]

Unfortunately, for this **, I am getting this, and I'm pretty sure the Heuristics I'm using are fine, as it IS the distance formula....

A basic outline of my code is...

```
Define Functions / Variables (Openset, etc)

While No Goal and OpenSet > Value do
    If NOT the goal
    Get the Lowest Ranked Items in OpenSet
    Add to closed set

    For each neighbor pulled from premade calculated stuff do
        Calculate FScore, GScore, HScore
        If Neighbor in OpenSet and Cost less then the GScore of the item in open // In this case, the item in open is the one identified
            Remove it from open 
        If Neighbor in Closed and Cost loss then the GScore of the item in closed 
            Remove it from Closed
            **Thing that should not happen, but does anyway... :(
        If the Neighbor is not in Closed or Open
            Add it to open
    Else it is the Goal
        Say found Goal (Stop loop)
Reconstruct path
```

### Actual Code

```
local function AStar(Start, Goal)
    print("AStar start")

    Start["GScore"]     = 0                                -- Distance from start.  
    Start["HScore"]     = Heuristic(Start,Goal)            -- Estimated Distance from Goal
    Start["FScore"]     = Start.GScore + Start.HScore      -- The Final Score

    local OpenSet       = {Start}                          -- The OpenSet is the set of nodes that need to be check.  In each repetition, it pulls out the smallest 'Scoring' one, and checks it.  
    local ClosedSet     = {}                               -- The ClosedSet is the set of nodes that have already been visited

    local Continue      = true                                 -- Until the Goal is found, continue will be true.  
    local LowestNode, IndexVal
    local Reps          = 0

        local function GetLowestRankInOpen()
            local LowestRanks = {}
            local LowestNode, IndexVal;
            local CurrentNodeFScore = math.huge
            print("OpenSet has :"..#OpenSet.." options")
            for Index, Node in pairs(OpenSet) do
                if Node.FScore < CurrentNodeFScore then
                    CurrentNodeFScore = Node.FScore
                    LowestNode = Node
                    IndexVal = Index;
                    LowestRanks = {}
                    LowestRanks[#LowestRanks+1] = {Node = Node,Index = Index}
                elseif Node.FScore == CurrentNodeFScore then 
                    LowestNode = Node
                    IndexVal = Index;
                    LowestRanks[#LowestRanks+1] = {Node = Node,Index = Index}
                end
            end
            return LowestRanks--LowestNode, IndexVal;
        end

        local function NodeIsTransversable(NodeX, NodeY)
            local MapX = Map[NodeX] -- Node out of bounds?
            if not MapX then 
                print("Node out of bounds")
                return false
            end
            local MapXY = MapX[NodeY] -- Node out of bounds?
            if not MapXY then
                print("Node out of bounds")
                return false
            end
            return MapXY.Transversable 
        end

        function NodeIsInOpenSet(NodeX, NodeY)
            for Index, Node in pairs(OpenSet) do
                if ((Node.X == NodeX) and (Node.Y == NodeY)) then
                    return true, Node, Index
                end
            end
            return false
        end

        function NodeIsInClosedSet(NodeX, NodeY)
            for Index, Node in pairs(ClosedSet) do
                if ((Node.X == NodeX) and (Node.Y == NodeY)) then
                    return true, Node, Index
                end
            end
            return false
        end

        local function ReconstructPath(Node, Tab)
            Tab = Tab or {}
            table.insert(Tab, Node)
            return Node.Source and ReconstructPath(Node.Source, Tab) or Tab;
        end

        local function Check(Num) -- Basically just debugging...  Not sure if it worked too well... 
            for _, Node in pairs(OpenSet) do
                if Node.FScore <= Num then
                    print("failed @ "..Node.FScore)
                end
            end
        end

        local SourceNode

    while ((#OpenSet > 0) and Continue) do
        LowestNodes = GetLowestRankInOpen()
        for _, TheNode in pairs(LowestNodes) do
            SourceNode = TheNode
            local LowestNode = TheNode.Node
            local IndexVal = TheNode.Index
            Reps = Reps + 1
            print("Loop #: "..Reps.." | Open #: "..#OpenSet)
            print(LowestNode and "Lowest node is there" or "Lowest node is not there")
            print("X: "..LowestNode.X.." Y: "..LowestNode.Y)

            local LowestNodeX = LowestNode.X
            local LowestNodeY = LowestNode.Y
            print("FScore: "..LowestNode.FScore)
            Check(LowestNode.FScore)
            wait(0.1)
            if not ((LowestNodeX == Goal.X) and (LowestNodeY == Goal.Y)) then
                ClosedSet[#ClosedSet+1] = LowestNode
                OpenSet[IndexVal] = nil

                if OpenSet[IndexVal] then
                    print("Hack")
                end

                RenderNiceBrick(LowestNodeX, LowestNodeY, BrickColor.new("Mid gray"))
                for _, NeighborNode in pairs(Map[LowestNodeX][LowestNodeY].Neighbors) do
                    local NeighborNodeX                 = NeighborNode.X -- Speed things up
                    local NeighborNodeY                 = NeighborNode.Y
                    if NodeIsTransversable(NeighborNodeX, NeighborNodeY) then
                        local NeighborGScore        = LowestNode.GScore + Heuristic(LowestNode, NeighborNode)
                        local NeighborHScore            = Heuristic(NeighborNode, Goal)*1.01
                        local NeighborFScore        = NeighborHScore + NeighborGScore
                        local NodeIsInOpen, OpenNode, OpenIndex         = NodeIsInOpenSet(NeighborNodeX, NeighborNodeY)
                        local NodeIsInClosed, ClosedNode, ClosedIndex       = NodeIsInClosedSet(NeighborNodeX, NeighborNodeY)

                        if NodeIsInOpen and NeighborGScore < OpenNode.GScore then
                            RenderNiceBrick(NeighborNodeX,NeighborNodeY, BrickColor.new("Bright orange"), NeighborFScore)
                            OpenSet[OpenIndex] = nil
                        end

                        if NodeIsInClosed and NeighborHScore < ClosedNode.GScore then
                            RenderNiceBrick(NeighborNodeX,NeighborNodeY, BrickColor.new("Bright red"), NeighborFScore)
                            ClosedSet[ClosedIndex] = nil
                        end

                        if not NodeIsInClosed and not NodeIsInOpen then
                            RenderNiceBrick(NeighborNodeX,NeighborNodeY, BrickColor.new("Bright blue"), NeighborFScore)
                            local NewNode = {}
                            NewNode.X           = NeighborNodeX
                            NewNode.Y           = NeighborNodeY
                            NewNode["GScore"] = NeighborGScore
                            NewNode["HScore"] = NeighborHScore
                            NewNode["FScore"] = NeighborFScore
                            NewNode.Source  = LowestNode
                            OpenSet[#OpenSet+1]     = NewNode
                        end
                    else
                        RenderNiceBrick(NeighborNodeX,NeighborNodeY, BrickColor.new("Hot pink"))
                        print("Can't walk on dat")
                    end
                end
            else
                RenderNiceBrick(LowestNode.X,LowestNode.Y, BrickColor.new("Bright yellow"))
                Continue = false
                print("Found goal")
            end
        end
    end
    print("Done with A*")
    return true, ReconstructPath(SourceNode, {});
end
```

### Output

The output kind of looks like... 
(From the game I'm writing it for)
http://youtu.be/MNnWHRU7NtU

Notes
- Numbers are FScore
- Red = Finish
- Green = Start

Actual Output Example:

```
failed @ 59.430702270978
OpenSet has :102 options
Loop #: 156 | Open #: 102
Lowest node is there
X: 160 Y: -13
FScore: 59.424070168796
failed @ 59.424070168796
OpenSet has :104 options
Loop #: 157 | Open #: 104
Lowest node is there
X: 159 Y: -12
FScore: 59.417896359916
failed @ 59.417896359916
OpenSet has :106 options
Loop #: 158 | Open #: 106
Lowest node is there
X: 158 Y: -11
FScore: 59.412223982381
failed @ 59.412223982381
OpenSet has :108 options
Loop #: 159 | Open #: 108
Lowest node is there
X: 157 Y: -10
FScore: 59.407101745211
failed @ 59.407101745211
OpenSet has :110 options
Loop #: 160 | Open #: 110
Lowest node is there
X: 156 Y: -9
FScore: 59.402584854429
failed @ 59.402584854429
OpenSet has :112 options
Loop #: 161 | Open #: 112
Lowest node is there
X: 155 Y: -8
FScore: 59.398736129429
failed @ 59.398736129429
OpenSet has :114 options
Loop #: 162 | Open #: 114
Lowest node is there
X: 154 Y: -7
FScore: 59.395627356727
failed @ 59.395627356727
OpenSet has :116 options
Loop #: 163 | Open #: 116
Lowest node is there
X: 153 Y: -6
FScore: 59.393340941897
failed @ 59.393340941897
OpenSet has :118 options
Loop #: 164 | Open #: 118
Lowest node is there
X: 152 Y: -5
FScore: 59.391971938836
failed @ 59.391971938836
OpenSet has :120 options
Loop #: 165 | Open #: 120
Lowest node is there
X: 151 Y: -4
FScore: 59.391630560343
failed @ 59.391630560343
OpenSet has :122 options
Loop #: 166 | Open #: 122
Lowest node is there
X: 150 Y: -3
FScore: 59.392445307867
failed @ 59.392445307867
OpenSet has :124 options
Loop #: 167 | Open #: 124
Lowest node is there
X: 149 Y: -2
FScore: 59.39456690506
failed @ 59.39456690506
OpenSet has :127 options
Loop #: 168 | Open #: 127
Lowest node is there
X: 148 Y: -1
FScore: 59.398173284976
failed @ 59.398173284976
OpenSet has :128 options
Loop #: 169 | Open #: 128
Lowest node is there
X: 163 Y: -11
FScore: 59.484589358667
failed @ 59.484589358667
OpenSet has :205 options
Loop #: 170 | Open #: 205
Lowest node is there
X: 164 Y: -12
FScore: 59.498131722924
failed @ 59.498131722924
OpenSet has :204 options
Loop #: 171 | Open #: 204
Lowest node is there
X: 165 Y: -13
FScore: 59.511707387983
failed @ 59.511707387983
OpenSet has :206 options
Loop #: 172 | Open #: 206
Lowest node is there
X: 166 Y: -14
FScore: 59.525313655834
failed @ 59.525313655834
OpenSet has :207 options
Loop #: 173 | Open #: 207
Lowest node is there
X: 167 Y: -15
FScore: 59.53894811221
failed @ 59.53894811221
OpenSet has :208 options
Loop #: 174 | Open #: 208
Lowest node is there
X: 168 Y: -16
FScore: 59.552608590246
failed @ 59.552608590246
```

If you guys can see any problems with my procedure or logic, please tell me. I'm sure it's something stupid I overlooked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an existing Lua implementation,
http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/pathfinding-module